# c++ method as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to specialize std::unordered_map for a class X with a custom hash and a custom equality. The problem is that both the equality and hash functions do not depend only on the object(s) of class X but also on data in another (fixed) object of another class Y. Here is a toy example (with only the hash function) of what I want to do:

```
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;
struct Y {
  bool b;
  struct X {
    size_t i;
  };
  size_t hash(const X &x) {
    return x.i + b;
  }
  unordered_map<X, int, hash> mymap;
};
```

The problem is that the function hash in the template specialization is a method and the compiler complains ("call to non-static member function without an object argument"). What I want is that y.mymap uses y.hash(). Any way to do this?

Note that in the real code Y is also a template, in case it matters.

Thanks!

EDIT: To clarify, instead of the boolean b in my code I have a vector with data that is needed in comparing objects of type X. Some data is added when an X is created, so the vector is not constant, but the data for a given X does not change after it is added, so the hash for a given X never changes (so in a sense it depends only on X as required for a hash). The main reason I use this approach is to save memory since this data is a lot and is usually shared.

Comment: My guess is you need a static or global (no member) hash function resp. an object declaring the function call operator. In your case it's unclear to me why a hash for `X`s considers the value of the containing `Y` which prevents `hash` from being static.

Comment: The template parameters for "functions" in the C++ StdLib are types of *function objects*. You'll have to create a function object type to pass to `unordered_map`. To implement stateful function objects, one typically uses either lambdas or a custom class with an overloaded `operator()`. An object of that class must be passed to the constructor of the map, otherwise it will be default-constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `function<size_t(X const&)>` and e.g. `bind`, but as type erasure is not necessary in this case, here is a simpler solution:

```
struct Y {
    bool b;
    struct X {
        size_t i;
        bool operator==(X x) const {return i == x.i;}
    };
    size_t hash(const X &x) {
      return x.i + b;
    }

    struct Hasher {
        Y* this_;
        template <typename T>
        auto operator()(T&& t) const
          -> decltype(this_->hash(std::forward<T>(t))) {
            return    this_->hash(std::forward<T>(t));
        }
    };

    unordered_map<X, int, Hasher> mymap;

    Y() : b(false),
          mymap(0, {this}) {}
};
```

As mentioned by @dyp in the comments, you have to be careful with special member functions since we implicitly store `this` in `mymap` - i.e. the compiler-generated definitions would copy the `this_` pointer. An example implementation of the move constructor could be

```
Y(Y&& y) : b(y.b), mymap(std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(y.mymap)),
                         std::make_move_iterator(std::end  (y.mymap)), 0, {this}) {}
```

Comment: I think you'll have to write custom special member functions because of the backref (storing `this` in a data member), or delete them.

Comment: @dyp I can't be bothered to write all those out though, I just gave an example for the move ctor.

Comment: That's alright. Since the state may not be changed, one could also consider copying it into `Hasher`. The `hash_function` observer even allows `Y` to access that state, although (for some reason) only via a copy.

Comment: This seems to be what I needed, even though I do not understand everything you have written (like "{this}" and "-> decltype(this_->hash(std::forward<T>(t)))"). I am looking them up now. About the special functions, since I am not going to copy Y, do you think I still need to define them? I only define the constructor and I do not allocate memory directly since I use the standard containers.

Comment: If someone wondered this too, "{this}" is aggregate initialization for the Hasher object. By doing this you can skip defining a costructor, right?

Comment: I tried your suggestion without the "-> decltype(...))" and the std::forward (I can't make sense of them and I prefer to avoid using things I don't understand), but it seems to work fine. I also did not write custom special member functions but as I said Y objects are never copied and they do not allocate memory explicitly so, maybe there is non need for it.

Comment: @Giovo Yes, correct - {this} avoids the need for defining a ctor. Also, the -> decltype ... Is more generic, but you can use the actual types right away if you're unfamiliar with trailing-return-types or decltype atm.

Comment: @Giovo well, if you neither assign or copy Ys, just delete copy assignment and ctor?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately what you want to do is not legal. See 17.6.3.5/Table 26:

> `h(k)` The value returned shall depend only on the argument k.

It's pretty clear that you aren't allowed to have the hash depend on a member of `Y` as well as `X`.

EDIT: Just in case you meant for `b` to be const in your `Y` class there is a solution (I didn't compile this yet, I will if I get a chance):

```
struct Y
{
    explicit Y(bool config) : b(config), hash_(config), mymap(0, hash_) { }
    const bool b;

    struct X
    {
        size_t i;
    };

    struct Hash
    {
        explicit Hash(bool b) : b_(b) { }
        size_t operator()(const X& x) const
        {
            return x.i + b_;
        }

    private:
        bool b_;
    };

    Hash hash_;
    unordered_map<X, int, Hash> mymap;
};
```

Comment: *"on data in another **(fixed)** object of another class Y"* This member that the function depends on does not change its value, hence h(x) for equivalent x should always produce the same value.

Comment: @Columbo The bool member is non-const so it's not at all clear to me that it will never change.

Comment: Move-assignment? Eitherway, the asker tells us it is fixed, so that's simply our assumption.